# Split XML into multiple documents in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a large number of XML documents that look like this:

```
<root xmlns="urn:foo" xmlns:bar="urn:bar">
  <Entity>
    <bar:field>Data</bar:field>
    <bar:other>Other data</bar:other>
    <bar:more>More data</bar:more>
  </Entity>
  <Entity>
    <bar:field>Data</bar:field>
    <bar:other>Other data</bar:other>
    <bar:more>More data</bar:more>
  </Entity>
</root>
```

With up to 1000 Entity nodes under each root node. I would like to split each of these out into its own document *without writing to disk* if that is possible.

I am familiar with XSLT 2.0 and know that I can accomplish this with Saxon using xsl:result-document but that writes to disk in all cases, doesn't it? Is there any way to intercept the output as a String? I'm working in Java and the original data is the result of a REST call, so it's coming in as an InputStream that I'm currently writing to a String.

Comment: Write a SAX parser to interpret the input stream. The parser can split the data into two (or more) output streams.

Comment: also, be _very_ careful when working with XML data as String/Reader.  it is easy to corrupt the data that way.

Comment: xsl:result-document output bypasses normal result writing from my experience, writing to a file specified by the 'href' attribute.

Comment: I think that http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.lib/OutputURIResolver and the method http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon/Controller@setOutputURIResolver should allow you to provide your custom OutputURIResolver that makes sure the result documents are not written to the file system but are for instance buffered in memory with a StringWriter.

Comment: I was able to figure out and use the OutputURIResolver, thanks @Martin. I'm saving the StringWriters into an ArrayList and then having to iterate over that to get the Strings, but I guess there's no other way. Thanks! If you make an answer with this info I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon 9 allows you to provide an http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.lib/OutputURIResolver with the http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon/Controller@setOutputURIResolver method that can then handle any `result-document` in a custom way, for instance by writing to a StringWriter in memory instead of to a file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

What about parsing it into a Document, running the `/root/Entity` Xpath expression on it, looping over the NodeSet, and adopting each Node into a new, empty Document?

Comment: This might be what I have to do, although I was hoping to avoid using Java's horrible XML libraries. I was hoping I could do it with a stylesheet.

Comment: They're about as horrible as the browser's DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple XSLT 2.0 transformation and run this umpteen times against the original file from a Java program and catch Saxon's standard output in the Java program.

How to invoke another program from Java: use ProcessBuilder and run the Process. Details available on request.

Another option is to use JAXB to create an object tree, extract the Entity elements, create a small object tree and marshall that to a string. This would be very much faster.

Comment: Saxon's standard output from xsl:result-document is blank, the documents usually bypass standard output and get written to teh filesystem using the 'href' attribute.

Comment: @Derek - This answer does not mention the use of `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: Am I missing a way to get one document to output to many without using xsl:result-document? That's the only way I know of in XSLT 2.0

Comment: That's certainly correct. - Really, using JAXB would be fast and simple. (Do you have an XML schema?)

Comment: I have XSDs. I've never used JAXB but I'm open to it if it's the right tool.

Comment: Want me to procure a POC for outputting the singular XML docs from the one containing the list? No big deal.